# Google Pay Passes : How test Signup & Signin for a loyalty program?

Tags: android, google-pay

I filled in the necessary information in my class but I do not know how to test it. Nothing indicates it in the documentation. Moreover it refers to 2 variables MERCHANT_HOSTED_SIGNIN & MERCHANT_HOSTED_SIGNUP but impossible to know where they are!

For information, a part of my loyaltyClass :

```
 "discoverableProgram": {
        "kind": "walletobjects#discoverableProgram",
        "merchantSignupInfo": {
            "signupWebsite": {
                "kind": "walletobjects#uri",
                "uri": "https://mywebsite.com/googlePay/signup/",
                "description": "My description"
            },
            "signupSharedDatas": [
                "firstName",
                "lastName",
                "streetAddress",
                "addressLine1",
                "addressLine2",
                "addressLine3",
                "city",
                "state",
                "zipcode",
                "country",
                "email",
                "phone"
            ]
        },
        "merchantSigninInfo": {
            "signinWebsite": {
                "kind": "walletobjects#uri",
                "uri": "https://mywebsite.com/googlePay/signin/"
            }
        },
        "state": "trustedTesters"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to contact the Google Pay Passes team to activate registration and login.